# Convexity of functions

Tags: calculus, functions, convex-analysis

I'm trying to read up on convex/concave functions (is that the same as concave up, concave down?)

- If I were asked to prove a convexity of a function, what are the general steps to follow? (So far I know by standard definition, to form the conclusion based on the second derivative)
- In case I have a composite function: "**-ln$g(x)$**" , how do I prove that this is neither concave/convex ?

Comment: start with some background information (such as) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set and some definitions, and use your reasoning skills to prove the proposition. Memorizing a "step-by-step" approach to solving problems is the best way that I know to become really bad at math.

Comment: @JohnJoy the thing is I haven't ever had the concepts of convexity taught to me at school. I'm looking it up only now and it feels like noise in all directions.

I looked it up on Wiki and I understand the definition. But if I'm asked to prove something as convex/not convex/neither convex-concave I have no idea where to start and hence the question.


If I come to know what to look for, then I could use logic. noob here.

Comment: I would start by googling "convexity", "convex function", etc.. I would also ask myself what does concavity mean? what does the 2nd derivative represent? what does the second derivative tell us about the 1st derivative? always ask why, why, why.

Answer (score 1):

as you already said, looking at the second derivative is one of the main technices for prooving that a function is convex. As far as i know it suffices for continues functions to show, that $\forall a,b :\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} \geq f(\frac{a+b}{2})$ holds.
about the function $-ln(g(x))$ (i guess that is what you wanted to write):
if you want to prove that smth is not convex just look out if you can find a counterexample to the definiten, e.g. three values $a,b,c$ such that $a+b=2c$ and $f(a)+f(b)<2f(c)$

if you would tell us what g is, we could help you maybe further

Comment: It's an arbitrary function. I could assume it to be a function g(x) = ax + b ... or g(x) = x^2 perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

One of the goals of the book Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe ([free online](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)) is to teach people to recognize convex functions.  Aside from directly checking the definition or checking the second derivative, there are a bunch of ways of combining functions to create new convex functions.  For example, a supremum of convex functions is convex.  A conic combination of convex functions is convex.  Any norm is convex.  If $f$ is convex and $T$ is affine, then $g(x) = f(T(x))$ is convex.  There are various chain rules that can guarantee convexity.  There is a partial minimization rule that states that if $f(x,y)$ is a convex function on $X \times Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are convex sets), then $g(y) = \inf_{x \in X} f(x,y)$ is convex under certain assumptions.

Comment: In the case that g(x) is assumed to be affine, then the way to prove this would be to prove that an affine function is convex, and then the negative ln of that is convex too... did I get that right?

But then, it depends on what's g(x)... or are all ln(functions) convex? -- (looking up the book but it's all Greek and Latin at first glance)

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ such that $f(x) = -\log(x)$ if $x > 0$ and $f(x) = \infty$ otherwise.  Then $f$ is convex.  If $g(x) = a^T x + b$, for some vector $a$ and scalar $b$, then $h(x) = f(g(x))$ is convex by the rule about composition with an affine function.